# How can I make my app only available for iPhones and iPods in the App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I've designed my apps for iPhone/iPod screen sized and I want them only to show in the App Store if you are user of those devices. I don't want iPad users installing my apps and using them all stretched out and with black borders, and I don't intend designing for iPad too. So is there a way to make them only show up in the iPhone version of the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Xcode Project goto -> Target -> General Tab and set iPhone as the value for Devices in the Deployment Info Section.
[image]

Comment: Both my apps have iPhone selected, but I've seen some people have installed them in iPads (with iTunes Connect info).

Comment: Did you ever release a version that supported iPad?

Comment: No, never, but the iPad downloads are strangely low (like 5)

Comment: Also, when you submit the App to iTunes Connect there is an option to indicate the App only supports iPhone.

Comment: Yes, and I selected iPhone only. As proof, they only ask me for iPhone screenshots.

Comment: No idea really... but that setting in the illustration is the *official* way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I think it was just some sort of error. Anyway only like 1.5% of installs were from iPads. It would be great to like the question so more people see your answer.